# Is there a Java function similar to C++'s PBDS order_of_key?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, g++

In C++ we can use `__gnu_pbds` i.e. Policy based data structure. See the following code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include<ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace __gnu_pbds;

typedef tree<int, null_type, less<int>, rb_tree_tag,
        tree_order_statistics_node_update> PBDS;


int main()
{
        PBDS st;
        st.insert(1);
        st.insert(3);
        st.insert(4);
        st.insert(10);
        st.insert(15);
        for(int i=0;i<st.size();i++)
        {
           cout<<i<<" "<< *st.find_by_order(i) <<endl;
        } 
       cout<<st.order_of_key(5)<<endl; // 3
}
```

It has two important functionalities.

1. `find_by_order(k)` : which returns an iterator so we can access it's index in PBDS set.
2. `order_of_key(k)` : which return number of elements less than k.

Both the functions runs in `O(logn)` time. I want to use them in java. As these functions runs in logarithmic time Java `TreeSet` would be best match. for `find_by_order(k)` I have to convert `TreeSet` into a `List` to access its index. In `TreeSet` there are methods like `higher()` and `lower()` which return at least greater / at least smaller element. But I want the count of numbers less than k. So is it possible to do it in java ?

Help me figure it out. If I'm wrong at some point of time then let me know. Is their way to do it using `java 8 streams` ? orElse using Collection Framework ?

thanks✌️

Comment: This question is off-topic as C++, since it is not C++ that allows you to do this - you are using gnu-specific (non-standard) extensions. You might have more luck getting a useful answer if you use the `g++` tag and remove the C++ tag.

Comment: You could use as Map and a List for that...

Comment: Using TreeSet, you could do `tree.headSet(key, true).size()`

Comment: @racraman headSet().size() works well only for the elements which are in the treeset but order_of_key also works on the values which are not in the tree Set

Comment: `headset` does not require that the supplied key be present in the set.  Since `order_of_key` excludes the supplied key, I should not have had the `, true` (so just `tree.headSet(key).size()`)

Comment: Okay I got it that headset true trick

Comment: Great :).  To be clear, `headset` never requires that the supplied key be present either with or without the `true` argument;  all that that argument means is that that key element will be included in the result set if it did happen to be present in the original set.